# What is a better way for me to do these null checks and improve the performance of this code

Tags: java, performance, null, immutability

This job is talking about 30+ hours of time. This Iterator holds 800k records and the loop has to execute for each record and there are about 20+ of these checks in the same method. How can I avoid the cyclomatic complexity here?

```
CustomerPreference newRecord = null;

while (iterator.hasNext())
              {

final CustomerPreference current = iterator.next();

                     if (newRecord != null)
                     {
                           if (!newRecord.getEmail().equals(current.getEmail()))
                           {
                                  resList.add(newRecord);
                                  newRecord = current;
                           }
                     }
                     else
                     {
                           newRecord = current;
                     }

                     if (null != current.getEmailPref())
                     {
                           newRecord.setEmailPref(current.getHdCaEmailPref());
                     }

              else
                     {
                           if (newRecord.getEmailPref() == null)
                           {
                             newRecord.setEmailPref(NO_CHANGE);
                           }
                     }
```

Comment: How do you know this is the bottleneck in your program?  Have you run a profiler on it?

Comment: The answers you are getting are guesses, suspicions, generalities. Each one *might* be right. Don't you want to *know* what is costing time? so you can fix it and save a whole lot of those 30 hours? It doesn't cost anything to [*try this*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771).

Comment: Thank you so very much guys (OldProgrammer, Mike Dunlavey ) and sure i will follow your inputs..

Answer (score 1):

If this is just an internal app, take out the checks and enclose your code in a try/catch block, especially if the likelihood of a null reference is slim.

The catch block would just continue the loop.

Answer (score 0):

A null check probably takes one CPU cycle at most, let's call it 1ns to be conservative. 800k x 20 x 1 ns = 16 ms...

=> the null checks are not your problem!

Comment: A conditional branch that is not correctly predicted by the hardware takes a lot more than one cycle. The processor has to invalidate its entire pipeline, and begin fetching instructions from the correct address.

Comment: Fair enough but even though it's unlikely to be the main culprit for the slowness.

Answer (score 0):

Other method: check time !

Use a monitor, like JVM monitor: http://www.jvmmonitor.org/

Install it in Eclipse, and you can verify what really spends time ...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the real performance problem is outside of the shown code. Even if a string compare takes a microsecond and an iteration of the loop contains hundreds of them, a single iteration should not take longer than about a millisecond. And that should result in a runtime of about 10 to 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Those checks may not be the reason for performance degradation. But you can avoid possible logical errors by following good coding conventions.

I am following  below conventions.

1. Avoid `lazy initialization` of member variables as much as possible. Initialize the variables in declaration itself. This will handle NullPointerExceptions.
2. Decide on `mutability` of member variables early in the cycle. Use language constructs like `final` keyword effectively.
3. If you know that augments for method won't be changed, declare them as `final`.
4. Limit the `mutation` of data as much as possible. Some variables can be created in a constructor and can never be changed. Remove public setter methods if possible.
5. And finally, use `try{} catch{} finally{}` blocks at right places effectively.